# How can I wait data to be send using JSSC library

Tags: java, jssc

I'm using JSSC library for serial communication under Windows (if it's matter).

I need to know, how I can be sure that the data is sent to the device and I can close the serial port safe?

Note: Data can be with different size and in my case, a function like `Thread.sleep()` will not work.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes. If I close the serial port immediately after sending a couple of bytes, they are not received

Comment: Well you need to know, how is the device reading data. Please share some code where you are facing the problem